# While Inserting Data Showing Data as does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO public.employee
(id,first_name,last_name,salary,joining_date,department)
VALUES
(1, Monika, Arora, 100000, '2014-02-20 09:00:00', HR);
```

**Output:**

> ERROR:  column "monika" does not exist

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name said, string values, like 'Monika','Arora', need to get 'single-quoted'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monika, Arora and HR should be quoted like that:

```
INSERT INTO public.employee (id,first_name,last_name,salary,joining_date,department)
VALUES (1, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '2014-02-20 09:00:00', 'HR');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add single quotes, as this is how string constants are represented in SQL: `'Monika'`